# Opening a file associated with a GTK+ application (in C) via a double-click in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, gtk, ubuntu-16.04, mime

I have a GTK+3 program that I have written and it uses GKeyFile's to store user parameters. There is a default keyfile that is loaded when the application is executed that stores the previously used parameters, but the user has the option to store information at anytime into a GKeyFile with the extension "*.dc1" and open these files through the program. I am trying to get the application to fire when a user double-clicks on a file with the extension "*.dc1". I have associated the files with an icon, and I have also associated the files with the application by creating a new MIME type. The MIME XML instructions are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="application/x-dc1">  
   <comment>DC1 Configuration File</comment>
   <glob pattern="*.dc1"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

An icon in the form of an .svg file was also created. Then the following commands were performed:

```
sudo cp ccc_dc1.xml /usr/share/mime/packages
sudo cp application-x-dc1.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes
sudo cp application-x-dc1.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes
```

The MIME type file was appended by running:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/mime.types
```

and adding "application/x-dc1". Then the icons are added to the file extension with:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Humanity -f
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome -f
```

The .desktop file has the form:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=DC1
Comment=GUI
Exec=sudo taskset -c 6 /home/DC1/Codes/./CCC_DC1
Icon=/home/DC1/SourceFiles/Images/cytoDC1.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
MimeType=application/x-dc1;
Name[en_US]=DC1
```

And the following commands were performed:

```
sudo cp DC1.desktop /usr/share/applications
xdg-mime default DC1.desktop application/x-dc1
```

When this was done, the icon was associated with the file extension, but when I double click a file with that extension the icon appears in the Unity Launcher, blinks a few times, and disappears. My understanding is that when I file is opened via a double click, its absolute path is passed through argc/argv, but despite my Gtk program handling this in two ways:

1. By handling argv when using gtk_init() in main
2. By using the open signal when using GtkApplication

both instances fail when double clicking a file. However, when passing the name of the file on the command line, both methods succeed. This leads me to believe that it is not the application code, but something else that I can't put my finger on. The two Gtk examples are below. The first is using gtk_init:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
  GtkWidget * window;

  // Declare read_data of type data and a pointer;
  struct data read_data;

  gtk_init( & argc, & argv);

  read_data.builder = gtk_builder_new();
  read_data.keyfile = g_key_file_new();

  GError * err = NULL;
  GKeyFileFlags flags = G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_COMMENTS | G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_TRANSLATIONS;

  // Creating a GtkBuilder from a .glade file
  gtk_builder_add_from_file(read_data.builder, GLADE_FILE, & err);

  if (err != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read glade file: %s\n", err -> message);
    g_error_free(err);

    return 1;
  }

  // If the program isn't opened by double clicking a key-file, load the previously used parameters
  if (argv[1] == NULL) {
    // Load the GKeyFile from config (.dc1) file
    g_key_file_load_from_file(read_data.keyfile, "/home/DC1/SourceFiles/cfg.dc1", flags, & err);

    if (err != NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read keyfile: %s\n", err -> message);
      g_error_free(err);

      return 1;
    }
  }
  // If the program was opened by double clicking a key-file, load the parameters from that file instead
  else {
    // Load the GKeyFile from config (.dc1) file
    g_key_file_load_from_file(read_data.keyfile, argv[1], flags, & err);

    printf("The keyfile being loaded has path: %s\n", argv[1]);

    if (err != NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read keyfile: %s\n", err -> message);
      g_error_free(err);

      return 1;
    }
  }

....AND SO ON
}
```

And the second is using GtkApplication:

```
static void open_callback (GtkApplication *app, gpointer *files, gint n_files, __attribute__((unused)) gchar *hint, 
        __attribute__((unused)) gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  // Declare read_data of type data and a pointer;
  struct data read_data;

  read_data.builder = gtk_builder_new();
  read_data.keyfile = g_key_file_new();

  GError * err = NULL;
  GKeyFileFlags flags = G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_COMMENTS | G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_TRANSLATIONS;

  // Creating a GtkBuilder from a .glade file
  gtk_builder_add_from_file(read_data.builder, GLADE_FILE, & err);

  if (err != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read glade file: %s\n", err -> message);
    g_error_free(err);

    return;
  }

  gint i;

  // Open the file via the command line arguments (i.e. by clicking a *.dc1 file associated with the software)
  for (i = 0; i < n_files; i++)
  {
    gchar *filepath = g_file_get_path (files[i]);

    // Load the GKeyFile from config (.dc1) file
    g_key_file_load_from_file (read_data.keyfile, filepath, flags, &err);

    printf("The keyfile being loaded has path: %s\n", filepath);

    if (err != NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read keyfile: %s\n", err->message);
      g_error_free(err);

      return;
    }

    g_free (filepath);
  }

....AND SO ON
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to what I may be missing here, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Replace `Exec=sudo taskset -c 6 /home/DC1/Codes/./CCC_DC` with `Exec=gksudo taskset -c 6 /home/DC1/Codes/./CCC_DC`. Using `sudo` in the desktop file won't work, because there is no terminal. `gksudo` is a GTK+ frontend for `sudo` and will work similarly, except that it will use a graphical prompt for the password if necessary.

Comment: The solution was incredibly simple. Having forgot that command line arguments are being passed, I didn't realize that I had to update the sudoers file (the command to execute the app was in there to disable asking for a password - necessary when running a .desktop file with sudo) and append that line with a * to account for the extra command line arguments. Foolish in retrospect.